# Not showing the first page when started

Tags: android, pdf, android-studio

Good day, I'm almost new to pdf renderer on android studio > api 21, I found a simple code to read pdf on assets folder.
My Problem is that when it's load the first page of the file is not showing unless i press the next button. My application aims to read a user's manual pdf.

```
package com.bloxofcode.phase1app;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class UsersManual extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private Button next, previous;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_manual);

        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        render();
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage++;
                render();
            }
        });

        previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage--;
                render();
            }
        });


    }

    private void render() {
        try{
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            int REQ_WIDTH = imageView.getWidth();
            int REQ_HEIGHT = imageView.getHeight();

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            //File file = new File("/sdcard/Download/sample.pdf");

            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "Learning Python 5th Ed 2013.pdf");
            try
            {
                in = assetManager.open("Learning Python 5th Ed 2013.pdf");
                out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
            //ParcelFileDescriptor p = getApplicationContext().getAssets().openFd("Learning Python 5th Ed 2013.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();
            File f = new File(getFilesDir() + "/Learning Python 5th Ed 2013.pdf");
            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

            if(currentPage <= 0) {
                currentPage = 0;
            } else if(currentPage > renderer.getPageCount()) {
                currentPage = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
            }

            Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT);
            renderer.openPage(currentPage).render(bitmap,rect, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
            imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.invalidate();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you increment the page counter in onCreate before rendering?

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: I don't see why not. The difference between starting the activity and clocking the button is incrementing the page and calling render again. Maybe you actually need to call render, increase the counter, then render again in onCreate

Answer (score 1):

REQ_WIDTH and REQ_HEIGHT are 0. Try adding values to them relating to the screen size

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code I just cleaned it a bit

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class UsersManual extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private Button next, previous;
    private PdfRenderer renderer;
    int REQ_WIDTH = imageView.getWidth();
    int REQ_HEIGHT = imageView.getHeight();
    private int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users_manual);

        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        render();
        display();
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage++;
                display();
            }
        });

        previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage--;
                display();
            }
        });


    }

    private void render() {
        try {
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            REQ_WIDTH = imageView.getWidth();
            REQ_HEIGHT = imageView.getHeight();

            File f = new File(getFilesDir() + "/Learning Python 5th Ed 2013.pdf");
            renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
            count = renderer.getPageCount();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void display(){

        if (currentPage <= 0) {
            currentPage = 0;
        } else if (currentPage > count) {
            currentPage = renderer.getPageCount() - 1;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, REQ_WIDTH, REQ_HEIGHT);
        renderer.openPage(currentPage).render(bitmap, rect, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageView.invalidate();
    }


}
```